# H2 Add column only if column not exists

Tags: h2, alter

How to add a column to H2 database only if that column does not exists already in the table?

I am using schema.sql to create a database structure.

I have tried several combinations of code like this but nothing works:

```
ALTER TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME.column_name ADD COLUMN column_name VARCHAR (50);
```

h2 version: 1.4.199

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The valid syntax is

```sql
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50);
```

https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_add

Comment: Great, it works. Do you have an idea why the changing of the column name doesn't work:
v1:
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ALTER COLUMN IF EXISTS COLUMN_NAME_OLD RENAME TO COLUMN_NAME_NEW;
v2:
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME RENAME COLUMN_NAME_OLD TO COLUMN_NAME_NEW;

Comment: `ALTER TABLE … ALTER COLUMN …` has `IF EXISTS` clause only for the table and doesn't have it for the column. So you can disable this command only if your table doesn't exist, but you can't disable it if table exists and column doesn't exist. You can create a feature request for that functionality on GitHub: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues